# Why running generic aggregation method is many times slower?

Tags: .net, sql-server, performance, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I'm having performance problem with Entity Framework while using generic methods for data aggregation. When querying max value of (indexed) Id column of table with few hundred thousands of rows using generic methods I'm getting huge performance drop. I'm using code-generated int keys instead of sql identities, this code is used to get next new Id.

Here's sample illustration. `MaxTyped` uses `Max` on `db.Posts` (which is `DbSet<Post>`), while `MaxGeneric` uses generic method `max` to do the same.

```
static int MaxTyped()
{
    using (var db = new BloggingContext())
    {                    
        return db.Posts.Max(p => p.PostId);
    }
}

static int MaxGeneric()
{
    using (var db = new BloggingContext())
    {
        return max(db.Posts, p => p.PostId);
    }
}

static int max<T>(DbSet<T> set, Func<T, int> func) where T : class
{
    // intellisense says its IEnumerable.Max
    return set.Max(func);
}
```

On my not so old home desktop with quite fast hdd, `MaxTyped` on 100k rows runs in 0.5s, while `MaxGeneric` around 6.5s. This is one order of magnitude slower.

On my office old testing server we're having times of few seconds vs almost 10 minutes.

The only trace of the problem I've found is the difference in Intellisense's output for Max method in both cases: in `MaxTyped` it identifies method as `IQueryable.Max`, while in max used by `MaxGeneric` it says its `IEnumerable.Max`, what might mean EF is doing Max on all loaded entities and not in database. I tried casting `set` to `IQueryable<T>`, but nothing changed. Why there's such a difference? How to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the `MaxTyped` is executed "server side", so only a single row is returned, while `MaxGeneric` is executed "client side", so all the rows of the table are returned, "deserialized" to `int` and the "max(ed)" (this last step is the fastest one)

The real cost is in the passage of data between the SQL Server and the .NET application: less data has to be passed, the better it's.

Now try

```
static int max<T>(DbSet<T> set, Expression<Func<T, int>> func) where T : class
{
    // intellisense says its IEnumerable.Max
    return set.Max(func);
}
```

and see if `set.Max` is using the `IEnumerable<T>.Max()` or the `IQueriable<T>.Max()`. If it's using the second one, its speed should be around 0.5 secs.

The difference is that `IQueriable<T>.Max()` accepts only `Expression<Func<T, int>>`, while `IEnumerable<T>.Max()` accepts `Func<T, int>`, and when you write `p => p.PostId` this can be an `Expression<Func<>>` or a `Func<>` depending on the type of variable it's put in.